# how data types in the Java programming language map to the data types in native programming languages such as C and C++,specifically

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

chapter 3 of the book "the Java Native Interface Programmer’s Guide and Specification",which says "The mapping of primitive types is straightforward",I'm a little confused about the sentence.
As we know that the size of c data types is uncertain,it depends on the environment where the program run ,complie...
such as the size of int type may be 2 bytes or 4 bytes.
But the size of java data types is definite.the size of int is 4 bytes.

so,how does jni map the data types between java and c/c++ clearly.

any answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in C, there is a module called [`stdint.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) which defines the types `int64_t`, `int32_t`, and friends, which does make the mapping "straightforward."

But you're right to note that in any particular implementation of C, the size of plain old `int` is not specified exactly.  The author was indeed pretty loose with the word "straightforward," and was assuming you would read the claim as something like "Java's `int` maps to the C signed integer type of 32 bits."

Comment: now ,I have a conclusion that there may be several size of a data type
in c/c++.but it will select one which has the same size of java data type.In other words,the map must between the same size of both.

am i right?

Comment: @ghui: Indeed. It has to, else the side with the biggest integer type could pass a value too large for the other side to hold.

Answer (score 1):

The [jni.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/jb-mr2-release/include/nativehelper/jni.h) header defines appropriate primitive types: jint, jlong, jchar, and so on.  These are declared to match the sizes of the corresponding Java primitives.  Use these in your JNI code.